# Javascript: push an entire list?

Tags: javascript

Is there a built in way to append one list into another like so:

```
var a = [1,2,3];
a.append([4,5]);
// now a is [1,2,3,4,5];
```

`concat()` does something similar but returns the result. I want something that modifies the existing list like `push()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript push array values into another array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156101/javascript-push-array-values-into-another-array), [how to do a “flat push” in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007744/how-to-do-a-flat-push-in-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extend an existing JavaScript array with another array, without creating a new array](//stackoverflow.com/q/1374126/90527)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`push` will work, but you also need to use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Apply).

```
var a = [1,2,3];
a.push.apply(a, [4,5])
```

Comment: That needs to be `Array.prototype.push.apply`, I think.

Comment: @lonesomeday: you think correctly. `a.push.apply` will also work. I apparently split the difference.

Comment: @Kooilnc: the MDC documentation for `apply` (linked to in the answer) should cover it. Read it and let me know if you need more.

Comment: it's ok, forgot about the *argsArray*

Comment: It's less redundant (i.e. not using the array name *twice*), but still shorter than using `Array.prototyp.push.apply()` is to use `[].push.apply()`. -- And according to the JSPerf test "[concat vs push.apply](http://jsperf.com/concat-vs-push-apply/11)" it's pretty efficient as well.

Answer (score 34):

If you are using ES6 you can use the spread operator

eg :-

```
listOne = [1,2,3]
listTwo = [4,5,6]
listTwo.push(...listOne)
```

Answer (score 24):

```
var list = [1, 2];
```

People already showed you how to do this with:

1. push: `list.push.apply(list, [3, 4]);`
2. concat: `list = list.concat([4, 5]);`

But I want to tell about [ES6 spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator): `list.push(...[3, 4]);`.

Keep in mind that currently not many browsers support it (you can use transpilers).

Comment: I found out that, if your array is very big and you insert only about 5-20 elements, the `list.push.apply` method is extremely much faster.

Comment: @Aloso Thanks, you can post this as an answer with a corresponding benchmark (it would be nice to see the numbers behind "extremely much faster" and "very big"

Comment: I don't think that this deserves a whole answer. However, I made a jsperf for testing speed: https://jsperf.com/array-vs-linkedlist-concat

Comment: Ok, there's more to it, so I will add an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Because I just wrote a web application where a lot of arrays have to be concatenated and where performance is critical, I tested which method is fastest [in this jsperf](https://jsperf.com/array-vs-linkedlist-concat). The results are quite interesting.

In my test, I add 10 elements to a list or array of 10,000 elements.

Here are the test cases, from fastest to slowest. Results are measured in Chrome 62, but Firefox 47 performs similarly:

- `LinkedList.prototype.concat`: 90,313,485 ops/sec

  ```
  list.concat(concatList);
  // This function has to change only 1-2 refences
  ```
- `Array.prototype.push` in a **for loop**: 3,794,962 ops/sec

  ```
  for (var i = 0, len = concatArr.length; i < len; i++) {
      array.push(concatArr[i]);
  }
  // Probably fastest in real life
  ```
- `Array.prototype.push.apply`: 2,193,469 ops/sec

  ```
  array.push.apply(array, concatArr);
  ```
- `Array.prototype.concat`: 22,701 ops/sec

  ```
  array = array.concat(concatArr);
  ```

Unfortunately, the `LinkedList` version doesn't work if you want to concat an array/list to **multiple** `LinkedList`s. It also has no benefit if an array has to be copied to a `LinkedList` before every concat operation. So, for me, the winner is the **for loop**.

One reason to **not use `Array.prototype.push.apply`** is that it fails if the concatenated array is too big. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4156156/3393058), the concatenated array can't have more than 500,000 elements in Firefox and 150,000 elements in Chrome.

I excluded the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) because it is not supported by all browsers. In Chrome, it's about as fast as `Array.prototype.push.apply`, in Firefox it is a bit slower.

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
a = a.concat([4, 5]);
// a is now [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Wouldn't just pushing them one after the other be more efficient?

Comment: @shoosh, yes, probably it would be more efficient.

Comment: consider following code before concatenating: var b = a; The variable a changes, but b is still 1, 2, 3. [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rg3sj/)

Comment: Wow! Using `concat` is *bizzarely* inefficient! [http://jsperf.com/concat-vs-push-apply/10]

Comment: Two years later Chrome 37 and IE11 both report concat as 67% faster than push apply...

Comment: This is **wrong**. `a.concat` does not modify the array - the code `var a = [1, 2, 3];var b = a;a = a.concat([4, 5]);` results in `a` not referencing the same object as `b`, and `b`'s object not having `[4, 5]`.